# How to use mysql "json_contains" with JPA Specification

Tags: jpa

I want use JPA Specification to query my data.
The column is annotated by @Type(type = "json").
And I generated predicate with those code:

```
 cb.like(root.get<String>("exampleColumnName"), "%queryParam%")
```

finally,I got the sql like this and it cant get anyting form mysql:

```
select * from XXX where exampleColumnName like '"%queryParam%"'
```

But the except sql is

```
select * from XXX where exampleColumnName like '%queryParam%'
```

I trace the code to com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.internal.JsonTypeDescriptor and found the "unwrap" method is different with org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.StringTypeDescriptor.

I want to generate a LikePredicate about the column annotated by @Type(type = "json");

Comment: may be your case same with me, this my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60796451/how-to-query-in-jsonb-postgresql-and-convert-to-predicate-jpa

Answer (score 3):

Finally，I found a method “function” can do what I want

```
return Specification { root, _, cb ->
            val predicate = cb.conjunction()
            val expressions = predicate.expressions

            if (!queryForm.areaCode.isNullOrBlank()) {
                expressions.add(
                    cb.equal(
                        cb.function(
                            "JSON_CONTAINS",
                            String::class.java,
                            root.get<String>("areaCodeList"),
                            cb.literal(jacksonObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(arrayOf(queryForm.areaCode))),
                            cb.literal('$')
                        ), "1"
                    )
                )
            }
            predicate
        }
```