# How to query in jsonb postgresql and convert to predicate JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jsonb

i have stuck :)

does anyone know how query postgresql in jsonb
i have table USER

- INT id,
- Varchar name,
- jsonb categoryId

the example data in categoryId field like this = `[1,2,3,4,5]`

I have tried this query which works:

```
select * 
from user where categoryId @> '2'::jsonb ;
```

but how to query with multiple params like

```
select * 
from user 
where categoryId @> '1,3,4'::jsonb
```

and i will implement this to hibernate jpa/jpql-predicate, but i want to know native query first

Thankyou so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL you can use the `?|` [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) for this

```
select *
from "user"
where categoryid ?| array['1','3','4'];
```

That will return rows where at least one of the values is contained in the JSON array. If you want to find those that contain **all** values, use the `?&` operator instead.

---

To use the `@>` operator you would need to use a JSON array on the right hand side:

```
select *
from "user"
where categoryid @> '[1,3,4]'::jsonb
```

---

Note that `user` is a reserved keyword. You will have to enclose it in double quotes every time you want to refer to the table. I would highly recommend to find a different table name.

Comment: Works ! thank you so much, and how to convert to criteriabuilder in JPA , i have try with criteriabuilder.function but i still confuse to use,

i try like this, but error :
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.function("jsonb_contains", Integer.class,
      expPreferedCountry,
                       expPreferedCountry
               )));

Comment: @herure279: sorry, no idea. I don't use JPA